# In Angular 2, how to approach consuming plugin that is documented in and written for jquery?

Tags: jquery, angular, froala

My current situation is this..

I am installing and configuring [Froala](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor) which has a dependency on and is documented for jquery.

- [Angular 2 and 4 Froala WYSIWYG Editor - Extended Config](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/framework-plugins/angularjs-2-4#extend-functionality)

I know server side much better than JS/Angular.  And I know its best practice to avoid using jquery in Angular.

My current approach when this situation arises is to:

- View [git page of Angular Implementation of Library](https://github.com/froala/angular-froala-wysiwyg) if exists.
- Use IDEs "go to definition" to search for directives I can use.
- I then use @ViewChild if I don't find directives for what I need.

*What is the Angular way to configure and consume plugins like this?*  Is this a situation where following the docs and using jquery to configure is Ok?  Such as the following from Extended Config above:

```
  ngOnInit () {
    $.FroalaEditor.DefineIcon('alert', {NAME: 'info'});
    $.FroalaEditor.RegisterCommand('alert', {
      title: 'Hello',
      focus: false,
      undo: false,
      refreshAfterCallback: false,

      callback: function () {
        alert('Hello!');
      }
    });
  }
```

**Edit 1:** 
In response to comment.

- Its best practice to wrap jquery plugins in an Angular component.  - This gives me a good jumping off point to research and google more.

Comment: usually 3rd party components are wrapped into Angular componenents, check this article [Never again be confused when implementing ControlValueAccessor in Angular forms](https://blog.angularindepth.com/never-again-be-confused-when-implementing-controlvalueaccessor-in-angular-forms-93b9eee9ee83), specifically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ultimately approached this by:

- Abstracting into a new component.
- Incorporated [`ControlValueAccessor`](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor), although I am not entirely clear on all benefits of this approach.
- Created an interface for the weakly typed options.  I scraped these from their docs site.
- And on an as needed basis, will add @Input and @Output when I need to configure a setting.

I ultimately came up with the following:

```
declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'froala-component',
  template: `
    <div #froala [froalaEditor]="froalaOptions" (froalaModelChange)="onChange($event)" [(froalaModel)]="froalaModel"></div>
   `,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => FroalaEditorComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class FroalaEditorComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit {

  @ViewChild('froala') froalaEditor: ElementRef;

  @Input() froalaModel;
  @Output() private froalaModelChange = new EventEmitter();

  @Input() set height(value: number) {
    this.froalaOptions.height = value;
  }

  @Input() set width(value: string) {
    this.froalaOptions.width = value;
  }

  public froalaOptions: FroalaOptions = {};

  ngOnInit() {
    $ = $(this.froalaEditor.nativeElement);
  }

  // implements ControlValueAccessor Interface
  public registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  public registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  public writeValue(content: any): void {
    this.froalaModel = content;
  }

  // event handlers
  public onChange(x) {
    this.froalaModel = x;
    this.froalaModelChange.emit(this.froalaModel);
  }

  public onTouched() { }

  // froala methods - https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/methods
  public toggleFullScreen() {
    $.froalaEditor('fullscreen.toggle');
  }
}
```

I added an interface scraped from their options page to get intellisense for options like so:

```
export interface FroalaOptions {
  aviaryKey?: Boolean; /* ADOBE_CREATIVE_CLOUD_KEY */
  aviaryOptions?: Object; /* {
    displayImageSize: true,
    theme: 'minimum'
  } */
  charCounterCount?: Boolean; /* TRUE */
  charCounterMax?: Number; /* -1 */
  etc...
}
```

And on an as needed basis will add an `@Input` for or `@Output` when consuming.
So currently I can use like so:

```
<froala-component [(froalaModel)]="model.HTML" height=850></froala-component>
```